# How to load in a dynamic arrangement of structures the information of a binary file?

Tags: c, file, struct, binary, fread

I have a binary files that contains a sequence of:

```
0-9 char name[10];
10-11 unsigned int n;
12-12+2x4n float coords[n][2];
```

and I need to load this into a dynamic array of structures.

I want to keep all the information on my file in the type structures:
so i declared a struct like this:

```
typedef struct{
char name[10]
unsigned int n;
float coords[][2];
}sprites_t;
```

Then i make a function to load this in memory:

```
    size_t n = 0;
        sprites_t * s = malloc(sizeof(sprites_t)*INITIAL_PACKAGE);
        size_t reads;

       while((reads = fread(s + n,sizeof(sprites_t),INITIAL_PACKAGE,fi)) == INITIAL_PACKAGE ){
            sprites_t * aux = realloc(s,sizeof(sprites_t) * (n+INITIAL_PACKAGE));
            if (aux == NULL) {
                free(s);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            s = aux;
            n += INITIAL_PACKAGE;
        }
n += reads;
```

I can't make this thing as much as I want in memory. Because inside the binary file I have an "unsigned int n" that is the amount of rows that have the coordinate matrix, then my structures are flexible. How can I be able to read that N? And on the basis of that, finish building structures with the information that the files provides.

I really don't know if my code if all right. If someone has another strategy to load the information on a dynamic array of structures welcome be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your binary `name` field is exactly 10 characters long then you can, indeed, represent it as a `char[10]`, but you should be aware that unless it reliably terminates each name (so that there are actually only 9 usable characters), it is not then safe to treat that array as if it contained a C string.  If you want to be able to treat the name as a string, then declare your array one character longer, and use the extra space to ensure that the in-memory copies are properly terminated.

Other than that, your structure seems fine, and yours seems a reasonable use case for a flexible array member.  But everything else in the code presented is a disaster. In particular,

1. You cannot have an array of objects with flexible array members, at least not where the FAMs contain any data.  Even a dynamic array does not make sense here, because the elements do not have consistent size.  A linked list would be a better choice, or maybe a hash keyed by the `name` field if you happen to be planning to look them up by name.
2. Your code makes a lot of assumptions about data layout and representation, among them

   - that your implementation's in-memory representation of type `unsigned int` matches the binary file's representation in size, byte order, and (non-)usage of padding bits.  It probably does match with respect to padding bits, since they're rarely used.  It might do with respect to byte order.  It probably doesn't with respect to size.
   - that your implementation lays out type `sprites_t` without any padding between the end of `name` and the beginning of `n`.  You might be lucky there, but you would need to be.  Especially if your `unsigned int` is wider than two bytes, chances are high that the structure layout indeed does contain padding.
3. Flexible array members are flexible in the sense that *the program can provide* an appropriate amount of space for them, not in the sense that they flex automatically.  You seem not to be providing any space for yours, though you're not reading any, either, so that's moot on its face.

So, overall suggestions

- use a linked list or a hash, not an array.  For the former, I would adjust the data structure like so:

  ```
  typedef struct sprite {
      char name[11];        // includes space for a terminator
      uint16_t n;           // matches the data, except maybe in byte order
      struct sprite *next;  // to link these together into a list
      float coords[][2];    // flexible array of 2D coordinates
  } sprite_t;
  ```
- read the `name`, `n`, and `coords` members of each sprite separately
- most straightforward would be to allocate each structure only after you know how many sets of coordinates there are, so maybe

  ```
  char name[NAME_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };
  uint16_t n;
  if (fread(name, NAME_SIZE, 1, file) != 1) { /* handle EOF or I/O error ... */ }
  if (fread(&n, 2, 1, file) != 1) { /* handle EOF or I/O error ... */ }
  // swap n's byte order if appropriate ...
  sprite_t *sprite = malloc(sizeof(sprite_t) + n * sizeof(sprite->coords[0]));
  if (!sprite) { /* handle allocation failure ... */ }
  if (fread(sprite->coords, sizeof(sprite->coords[0]), n, file) != n) { /* handle EOF or I/O error ... */ }
  strcpy(sprite->name, name);
  sprite->n = n;
  append_to_linked_list(my_sprite_list, sprite);
  ```

Even that still assumes that the implementation's representation of type `float` matches the representation used in the file.  If it doesn't, then you'll need to patch that up, too.  That might take more or less effort, and "more" will certainly be the case if the sizes don't match, though that's unlikely.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed.
Really, thank you very much.